# HttpClient.GetStreamAsync() working on .NET Core and not working on .NET Framework

Tags: c#

I have implemented a class which uses `HttpClient.GetStreamAsync()` method (this class is in a first project). To test my class, I was using a .NET core project (in which i have the main function), and it was working perfectly.

I was asked to use a .NET Framework instead so I created new project (.NET framework) re-used the program.cs of the .NET core project but now when i run the program it is stuck in the `HttpClient.GetStreamAsync()` method until it reaches a "task was canceled" expectation.

I re-launched the .NET Core project, the method still works

```
using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(Client.GetStreamAsync("https://" + User + ".cloudant.com/" + Database + "/_all_docs").Result))
{
    JObject responseContent = (JObject)JToken.ReadFrom(new JsonTextReader(streamReader));
    System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken> ids = new KeyValuePair<string, JToken>("", null);
    JToken docsArray = responseContent.GetValue("rows");// type Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken {Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray}

    List<string> IDS = new List<string>();
    foreach (JToken doc in docsArray)
    {
        //Console.WriteLine(doc.ToString());
        string id = doc["id"].Value<string>();
        IDS.Add(id);
    }
    return IDS;
}
```

Comment: Don't use `.Result`, use proper `await` syntax, I'd be willing to bet this is your problem.

Comment: Would you please explain more, I m new to this and that's the only way i know

Comment: You need to learn how to write async code, it's too big a topic to write in a comment - go do some research.

Comment: Unless you show your code, we cannot help. Are you using await all the way up the call chain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was trying everything possible, and I found many solutions for problems with GetStreamAsync(), but none of them worked until a mate told me to try and close my previous StreamReaders and boom it worked.. well it's awkward that it was working on .NET Core and didn't on .NET Framework..
`streamReader.Close();`